How to parallelize map function in Spark?
I'm trying to call a function over a DataFrame. The function takes an id as input and queries a DynamoDB table. If the id exists in the table, it goes on to perform other tasks (like call another AWS service). I'm trying to call this function over all rows in the DF similar to python code:
df.apply(lambda x: func1(x))
but I keep running into Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
After following a few tutorials, I've tried using UDF and RDD as below -
Using UDF:
udf1 = udf(lambda x: func1(x, ddb_table), StringType()) # I tried returning a dummy string from func1
df_test = df.withColumn("response", udf1(df["id"]))
df_test.show()

Using RDD:
df_rdd = df.repartition(20)
final_rdd = df_rdd.rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x, ddb_table))

In both cases, I get the same thread lock error.
I would also like to leverage RDD to ensure only 50 concurrent calls are made to DynamoDB per second. Is there something I'm missing? What is the best way to ensure the concurrency?
I'm new to Glue and PySpark so I'm following a few blogs and learning on the go. Would appreciate any help I can get on understanding what I'm doing wrong.

In documentation of rdd.map is mentioned this :

Return a new RDD by applying a function to each element of this RDD

do you need this behavior?
This is how I would approach this task :
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

# Assuming 'pysparkdf' is your PySpark DataFrame and 'ID' is the column name
#separate the ids in a list (if ids are duplicated, this is an improvement)
distinct_ids = pysparkdf.select("ID").distinct().collect()

# To get a list of distinct ID values
id_list = [row['ID'] for row in distinct_ids]

# Define the size of each partition and the number of workers
partition_size = 10  # Adjust this value as needed
max_workers = 5  # Adjust this value based on your resource availability

# Create partitions of the ID list
id_partitions = [id_list[i:i + partition_size] for i in range(0, len(id_list), partition_size)]

# Define your function to process each ID
def process_id(id):
    # Replace with the code to process the ID
    print(f"Processing ID: {id}")

# Use ThreadPoolExecutor to process IDs in parallel
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    # Flatten the list of partitions and submit all IDs for processing
    futures = [executor.submit(process_id, id) for partition in id_partitions for id in partition]

# Wait for all tasks to complete and handle the results
for future in as_completed(futures):
    try:
        # Retrieve the result of each task
        result = future.result()
        # Use the result if needed
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Print the list of distinct ID values
print(id_list)


My understanding was that rdd.map is suppose to do the partitions and call the function in parallel (which is why I thought I could use it in a PySpark glue job). Is that not correct?
